# Explanation of the math behind the winding number algorithm

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algorithms

I'm working on an implementation of [this](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html#Winding-Number) algorithm in a tool, and like with all my implementations I like to have a really good understanding of the math associated with them. In reading how it is derived, I'm fine with the terms described until:

$$W(P) = C \rightarrow S^1$$

This is a continuous function that maps the point $C(u)$ on the curve $C$ to the point $w(P,u)$ on the unit circle $S^1$. However, I don't understand the following :

1. How the vector $c(P,u)$ and the unit vector $w(P,u)$ give us $W(P)$
2. How $W(P)$ maps some point $C(u)$ to $w(P,u)$ as a point, when it is a unit vector

The closest I can come to answering #2 myself is that $w(P,u)$ is a unit vector and thus it lands somewhere on $S^1$ since it has a radius of 1. Even that is a crude understanding, as I am not sure how $W(P)$ is derived from the two vectors, and thus how it "maps".

Comment: Points on a plane with an origin (and addition defined by the parallelogram law and multiplication by a scalar by homotethy) are vectors. If your idea of vectors are arrows, the arrows are those drawn from the origin to the point. When you subtract the point $P$ from the point $C(u)$ you get a new point $C(P,u)=C(u)-P$. If you have the Cartesian coordinates of the points subtraction is done component-wise. Suppose the components of $C(P,u)$ are $(f(u),g(u))$. They depend on the parameter $u$, which is a value between $0$ and $1$. Then $W(P,u)$ is the point with coordinates ...

Comment: ... $\left(\frac{f(u)}{\sqrt{(f(u))^2+(g(u))^2}},\frac{g(u)}{\sqrt{(f(u))^2+(g(u))^2}}\right)$. Note that the coordinates of this point satisfy $X^2+Y^2=1$. So, it is a point of the unit circle. Finally, because the point is in the unit circle, there is an angle $\theta(u)$ such that $\cos(\theta(u))=\frac{f(u)}{\sqrt{(f(u))^2+(g(u))^2}}$ and $\sin(\theta(u))=\frac{g(u)}{\sqrt{(f(u))^2+(g(u))^2}}$

Comment: Those angles $\theta$ are being used in the first algorithm to compute the winding number.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thank you. Can you expand on why you put the square roots in the denominator of the components? Everything else lines up perfectly for me from your explanation.

Comment: If $(a,b)$ is a point, then $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is its distance from the origin $(0,0)$, and $(a/d,b/d)$ is a point on the same ray from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ that satisfies $X^2+Y^2=1$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy That explains why the unit vector $w(P,u)$ mattered. Its the point along the ray (the vector $c(P,u)$) to $C(u)$ from $P$ (the origin). For my own sanity, why the need for the unit circle? Since the direction of the vector doesn't change, neither will the angle. Could one not compute the angle $\theta(u)$ without mapping to the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, all you need is the changes of the angle.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy So then why the need to map to the unit circle in the proof?